# Incremental game: Can I change programmatically limit and the amount of reward admob gives?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I'm building an incremental game where the user can see Rewarded Videos Ads with Admob and then receive some coins. Also, I have a Game Laboratory Screen where the user can upgrade some specifics things such as the score they earn per party and the coins they earn per party.
I wonder if I can set in my Laboratory an upgrade that can increase the number of Ads the user can watch and the amount of the coins the user can earn. On Android in Kotlin, I can simply get the rewards by the following method:

```
fun showRewardedAds(context: Context, onRewardedAdShowed: (Int) -> Unit) {
    if (mRewardedAd != null) {

        mRewardedAd?.show(context.getActivity()!!) { rewardItem ->
            val rewardAmount = rewardItem.amount
            var rewardType = rewardItem.type
            Log.d("TAG", "User earned the reward.")

            onRewardedAdShowed.invoke(rewardAmount)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Admob", "showInterstitial: The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        onRewardedAdShowed.invoke(-1)
    }

}
```

and then multiply the rewardAmount by a value stored in DataStore or
Room Database and also in Firestore to save data either if user uninstall the app.

**I want to know if it doesn't violate the admob policies.**

Comment: It is not required to use only the `rewards` returned by rewardItem, you can reward the user with whatever you want after the user has watched the ad completely.